# stretch image to 100% of viewport

Tags: html, css

I made an simple layout for an android application using html and css. The hole page has an background image, but i didnt declared it as:

```
 background-image: url(
```

Because so belong my information i cannot center it?
So that my next plan was to make an simple div that covers the image as you can see here:

```
<body>
<img src="foto.jpg" class="bg">

<div class="oben">
<h1>Playing Audio</h1>

<button onclick="playAudio('test.mp3')">Play Some Audio</button>
<button onclick="playAudio('test2.mp3')">Play Some Audio2</button>
</div>
</body>
```

My css is the following:

```
 .image{
position: relative; 
 width: 100%; 
 }
.oben { 
position: absolute; 
top: 20%; 
left: 0; 
width: 100%; 
}
```

SO now back to my actual problem, the image is not streching to the 100% of the viewport instead it is having 100% of its own width, what means around 200px! But i want to strech it all over the page! Thanks!

Comment: did you set the body width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's becuase there is no such thing as `.image`

You should try this

```
img.bg{
  position: relative; 
  width: 100%; 
}
```